# std priority and memsave priority in SCIP node selectors

Tags: scip

I noticed that there are two types of priorities in : `memsave prio` and `std priority`. When does it switch between the two? Is there a threshold parameter that can be set to influence this switching?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, parameter memory/savefac:

```
# fraction of maximal memory usage resulting in switch to memory saving mode
# [type: real, advanced: FALSE, range: [0,1], default: 0.8]
memory/savefac = 0.8
```

See also https://scip.zib.de/doc/html/PARAMETERS.php for documentation of SCIP parameters.

Comment: Thanks! What could be the maximal memory usage allowed? Is it also predefined?

Comment: sorry! I commented pretty early. I was able to get the parameter `limits/memory` to do what I want.